# Query Active Directory like Advanced Features in Active Directory Users and computers

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am writing an app the shows the active directory structure in a tree view. I would like to give the user the option like in Active Directory Users and Computers where you can Show/Hide certain 'Advanced' objects.

Does anyone know the what the LDAP query would be to simulate this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess theres no property for an AD attribute that defines it as an 'Advanced' object.  But nothing is stopping you to hadle it from the application side and define which are shown as 'Advanced'.